# J-2 visa: does 2-year old baby have to attend the visa interview?

Tags: j-visa

I don't want to bring my toddler to the visa interview. Normally, the waiting time before being called is several hours, and during that time he may be hungry or get upset. In those cases, it will be very difficult for me to control him.

But I'm afraid the officer may want to take my baby's biometric or something like that, and requires him to present at the interview.

Please answer **only if** you had this experience, i.e. leaving your baby at home for the J-2 interview. Thank you.

---

### UPDATE

I did the interview in London without my baby.

Comment: I know this question is very old, but did your visa appointment email say that your child had to attend? Mine say that all 3 of my kids have to attend, that's going to be a nightmare. I'm on a J1 and my kids and wife are on a J1.

Comment: @TitanBrave I believe you wanted to say your wife and kids are on J-2 (dependent of J-1). It's several years ago (we now have green card), but I believe children under some age do not need to attend.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [The Nonimmigrant Visa Interview](http://london.usembassy.gov/niv/interview.html) from the US Embassy in London:

> Applicants aged 14 - 79 are required to appear in person for an interview with a consular officer through a pre-arranged appointment.

Since J-2 is a *nonimmigrant* visa, the above is what applies to you. (The rules are [slightly different](http://london.usembassy.gov/iv/attending_interview.html) for *immigrant* visas.)

You may wish to check the web site for the US visa office you are actually going to visit, if it is not London. I found some variation in the posted rules depending on the particular embassy or consulate.